# Microsoft Office Programs Tag Prefix

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The main tag for each Microsoft Office program is not consistent on its usage of the **ms-** prefix.  For example:

- [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) - [Synonyms Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/synonyms) [ms-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-excel) is synonym-tag
- [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) - [Synonyms Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-word/synonyms) [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) is a different thing entirely but has many mis-tags
- [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) - [Synonyms Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/synonyms) No usage of [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) that I can find
- [powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint) - [Synonyms Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/powerpoint/synonyms) No usage of [ms-powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-powerpoint) that I can find
- [outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook) - [Synonyms Link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/outlook/synonyms) No usage of [ms-outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-outlook) that I can find

Two with **ms-** and three without.  **Should we have a standard of identity for Microsoft Office Programs?**

Comment: The [tag:word-2007] (and other versions) tags should be renamed to have the `ms-` prefix ([tag:ms-word-2007]) if the main tag for MS Word is [tag:ms-word]. I agree with MS-specific tags having the `ms-` prefix universally.

Comment: For MS-Word version tags, you sure have a winner. As well as for cleaning up the [tag:word], which is certainly not a synonym. Have fun with it all.

Comment: You can start by removing [tag:word] [from questions with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+ms-word) [tag:ms-word] while waiting for the synonyms to be created.

Comment: Assuming a consensus on using the **ms-** prefix, we'd have to get a 20k user or mod to edit those?

Comment: Only objection I have is how consistent do we want to get across MS programs.  Do we really want to call it `ms-visual-studio`?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think we can stop at the office suite.

Comment: @RubberDuck Almost forgot [tag:outlook]

Comment: theres also onenote, project, etc.

Comment: ms-project would be a relevant addition as project is ambiguous.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think they should be renamed. There is a pattern. Excel, powerpoint, outlook and onenote are as far as I can see brand names which cannot be easily confused. They can stay that way without an `ms-` prefix.

Word, access and project on the other hand are just words which can be easily confused with the Microsoft products. Those need the prefix and so they have them.

The other thing is that if you start with renaming the base tags, you would have to add a prefix to most of the other tags that contain "excel", "powerpoint" and "outlook" ("onenote" is the only one tag). The numbers are massive. I haven't counted, but by estimation at least 40 tags would have to be renamed. I doubt this helps anybody. I don't see a benefit in there.

Comment: And yet other sites use the ms- or microsoft- prefix on all MS product tags.

Answer (score 3):

The following tags should be updated to bring consistency to the Microsoft Office Suite:

**Excel**:

[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [excel-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2003), [excel-2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2007), [excel-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2010), [excel-2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2011) and [excel-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-2013) need `ms-` tag and synonymized with new tag.

**Word**:

[word-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-2003), [word-2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-2007), [word-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-2010), [word-2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-2011) and [word-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-2013) need `ms-` tag and synonymized with new tag to match main tag [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word).

**Access**:

All good.

**Powerpoint**:

[powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint), [powerpoint-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2003), [powerpoint-2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2007), [powerpoint-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2010), [powerpoint-2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2011) and [powerpoint-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-2013) need `ms-` tag and synonymized with new tag.

**Outlook**:

[outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook), [outlook-2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2003), [outlook-2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2007), [outlook-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2010), [outlook-2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2011) and [outlook-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-2013) need `ms-` tag and synonymized with new tag.

**23 total tags affected.**

Comment: Added for the purpose of which tags would need updated (half of the estimation in the other answer against changing)

Comment: @pnuts fun stuff.  I was mainly going on tags from the wiki entry.

Comment: Of all those, only ms-word-related tags really need doing, as ms-access apparently already is there (not sure whether ms-project is already done, it should too). The rest are pure OCD buzywork.

Comment: @Deduplicator Would bring us in line with other sites use ms- or microsoft- prefix on all MS product tags.

Comment: @pnuts What about the office-vba tags -- [word-vba], [excel-vba] etc.?

Comment: @pnuts Maybe we should burninate [tag:excel-vba]?  I wonder how many questions use all three: [tag:vba], [tag:excel], AND [tag:excel-vba]

Comment: @pnuts I assume that is all 3 in the same post?

Comment: @pnuts Isn't there still a place for (the horribly misnamed) [tag:excel-vba], to distinguish from programming [tag:excel-formulas] or specifically [tag:excel-addins]? Similarly a theoretical [tag:word-field-expressions] would be separate from [tag:word-vba].

Comment: @ZevSpitz Id say using [tag:vba] and [tag:excel] together will handle that.